# How do you think about implementing Installshield Basic MSI project without Installscript?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010

Do you think it is reasonable? or too restrictive??

Comment: It's actualy a really good question and I wish it hadn't been closed.  If you choose to use a Basic MSI and find the need to have custom actions but don't want to use InstallScript, you still have a variety of choices such as  EXE, C++ DLL, VBScript, C#/DTF et al.  It's a very reasonable design and actually what I've done for years.